# Predict future Data trends with current Data using sql script and them plot them over SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2017

I have been asked to create a trendline in SSRS, this trendline will the predicted future value based on current year data.
Here I have data of year 2018 and I needed to predict the trends of ClaimVolume for year 2019.

Please find the data

```
Month   Month Name  Year    ClaimVolume 
1       January     2018    13746         
2       February    2018    13412
3       March       2018    15143
4       April       2018    15655
5       May         2018    15190
6       June        2018    15365
7       July        2018    18943
8       August      2018    24305
9       September   2018    18893
10      October     2018    26659
11      November    2018    18696
12      December    2018    22367
```

Please help me in providing SQL query for the above task.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.